# How are you handling scores that can worsen (e.g. Elo rating) in Game Center?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, game-center, leaderboards

Currently, Game Center leaderboard scores can only change one-way (e.g. increase). This makes it impossible (I think) to deal with Elo ratings and the like. How are you getting around this in your leaderboards?

I have filed a bug report / feature request with Apple already FWIW.

Are you using a third-party leaderboard service? Rolling  your own?

Comment: I don't know anything about the Game Center... But did you try adding a negative score?

Comment: GC leaderboards only accept entries that are better than previous so this will have no effect.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? The answer below works for storing the scores, but not for using Game Center leaderboard views or rankings, so it would be impossible to know (without completely retrieving both leaderboards) in which position (rank) a player is. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Off the top of my head, if negative scores are not allowed: track positive and negative scores separately.

For instance, when writing the leaderboard:

```
// Pseudocode
points_for_win = 3;
points_for_loss = 2;

if (didWin)
    leaderboard.positive_score += points_for_win;
else
    leaderboard.negative_score += points_for_loss;
```

When retrieving the leaderboard, you can then compute the user's actual score by:

```
actual_score = leaderboard.positive_score - leaderboard.negative_score;
```